# Simple code to get inputs from user and then print them all at once not working?

Tags: python, user-input

I'm new to python and was doing a few "simple python tasks" to get started. I wrote a code to get a few numbers from the user and then after the user gives all numbers it prints them all.
This is my code:

```
number = [4]
for i in range(5):
    number[i] = int(input(f"Input number {i}: "))
print("Your numbers are: ", number)
```

The code works nicely for the first input, but after the second number is inputed it says there's in error in line 3.
I have no idea why, but I'm gussing it has to do with the list (this is my first time using a list, idk how to define it and such).

Thanks in advance <3

To get 5 inputs from the user and lastly print them out in a single "your numbers are: ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Error reason**: `number` is initialized as a `list` with a single element `[4]`. Since the loop tries to **access indices beyond the first index** of the list, it will result in an **IndexError**

**Code:**

```
number=[]
for i in range(5):
    number.append(int(input(f"Input number {i+1}: ")))
print("Your numbers are: ", number)
```

**Output:**

```
Input number 1: 5
Input number 2: 7
Input number 3: 4
Input number 4: 2
Input number 5: 1
Your numbers are:  [5, 7, 4, 2, 1]
```